# How to display discount in invoice pdf, magento. which is define in rules(Shopping cart price rules or catalog price rules)?

Tags: invoice, discount, pdf

How to display discount in invoice pdf, magento. 
which is define in rules like Shopping cart price rules or catalog price rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this code worked

```
if($item->getDiscountAmount())
{
    $lines[0][] = array(
        'text'  => $order->formatPriceTxt($item->getDiscountAmount()),
        'feed'  => 400
    );
}
```

Comment: please specify in which file you have added this.